# Wsdl not showing up in WAS 8.5 server

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

While migrating our application from JDK 1.6 to 1.7 . I took the different approach to generate the wsdl using maven (execute wsgen by calling bat file). After successfully generating the wsdl I am trying to 
deploy it on WAS server 8.5 . But found that wsdl is not showing in "Web Services Properties" under admin console.
While investigating by comparing the log which was built in jdk 1.6, I realize the below details are not present in my latest build (with jdk 1.7) which is there in previous version of log.

***Log****

`000000e7 WASAxis2Exten I   WSWS7037I: The /web-services/EntityIsdSearchService URL pattern was configured for the EntityIsdSearchService servlet located in the mrds-web-2.14.2.war web module`.

---

Hence the WAS Server 8.5 is unable to detect the already generated wsdl present in the war as the above details are not showing up in latest deployment.
Please guide if any one ever encounter such issue while running application in WAS 8.5 with wsdl compiled in JDK 1.7.

Also like to highlight while comparing wsdl of version 1.6 with 1.7 there are some difference like :

In JDk 1.6:

```
<input message="tns:findClientByGrid"/>
```

Changes to

`<input wsam:Action="http://clientcentral.hex.com/1_0/service/findClient" message="tns:findClientByGrid"/>` in jdk 1.7.

Please let me know if there is anything to do with it.

Comment: Adding more details:

Comment: Generating wsdl like this:

Comment: %Java_Home%\bin\wsgen -d target\classes -cp target\classes; .. dependent jars .. C:\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\..\lib\tools.jar -wsdl -r  target\classes com.hex.cobam.mrds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntityServiceEndpoint.